# How to assign every different client a different ID

Tags: javascript, php

I want my login page to have like a secure area, like say every time you visit my website the site assigns your IP or client a unique code (something like "A5K3JFSH54" something random) and then if that client say presses F12 and it comes up with a alert box saying "F12 was pressed!" and it bans that clients ID from the website and every time they enter the site it automatically sends them to a page called banned.php or something along the lines.

I already have the code which detects the F12 being pressed...

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 123) {
        alert('F12 was pressed!');
        window.location.href = "/banned.php";
    }
};
```

But I'm pretty much lost on how to assign each client a certain ID and if that ID is banned automatically send them else where and cannot access any other page.

Answer (score 0):

You could not detect same user and same IP return again to you page without old values. So you need to store either client ID or IP of user in database.

You can achieve this by sending ajax request to some page when user press F12. Store user's details in one table say "banned_IP" or "banned_users". And when your login page gets access by any user then do check if user's IP is stored in your table. If found record as banned then do redirect user on banned.php page.

Hope so it will help you.